GooglePlayGames、実績をアンロックしてもXPが0と表示される
GooglePlayの実績を実装したのですが、内部テスト版で動作確認したところ、実績をアンロックしてもXPが0と表示されます。
これは内部テスト版だからでしょうか、公開したアプリじゃないとXPは獲得できない？
手順：
1,公式のマニュアルに沿って実績を追加
2,内部テスト版でプレイ、実績をアンロックし、ポップアップを確認する
3,GooglePlayConsoleでXPを設定しているが、ポップアップの表示獲得XPが0であること、GooglePlayアプリのプロフィール画面から獲得XPが0であることを確認する
